# Use all backup sets to restore database with SMO

Tags: c#, sql-server, database, restore, smo

My problem is really simple.
I have a .bak file that contains one or more backup set.

When I'm using SMO to restore the database with this .bak file, it only takes the first backup set to do its work. It seems to ignore the remaining sets.

Why's that ?

See my code :

```
            //Sets the restore configuration
            Restore restore = new Restore()
            {
                Action = RestoreActionType.Database,
                Database = _databaseToRestore.DatabaseName,
                ReplaceDatabase = true
            };

            restore.Devices.Add(new BackupDeviceItem(_backupFilePath, DeviceType.File));

            Server server = new Server(_databaseToRestore.ServerName);

            DataTable fileList = restore.ReadFileList(server);
            string serverDataFolder = server.Settings.DefaultFile;

            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(serverDataFolder))
                serverDataFolder = server.Information.MasterDBPath;

            foreach (DataRow file in fileList.Rows)
            {
                restore.RelocateFiles.Add(
                    new RelocateFile((string)file["LogicalName"],
                    Path.Combine(serverDataFolder, _databaseToRestore.DatabaseName + Path.GetExtension((string)file["PhysicalName"]))));
            }

            //Gets the exclusive access to database
            server.KillAllProcesses(_databaseToRestore.DatabaseName);
            restore.Wait();

            restore.SqlRestore(server);
```

I thought the BackupDeviceItem could gives me a feedback on how many backup sets there's inside, this way I could warn the user, but it's not.

Anyone has a clue on this ?

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, fixed my problem.

The important field is `FileNumber` on the `Restore` object.
The default value is 1, so that's why it always took my first backup set.

I just had to set this property to the number of backup sets in the file and now it takes the most recent backup done.

Note : No differencial backups are implicated in this concern.

Answer (score 2):

I just found out that I could easily know how many backup sets the file contains.

```
DataTable backupSets = restore.ReadBackupHeader(server);
```

Now, a simple `backupSets.Rows.Count` can help me to warn the user.

Comment: This is very useful, thanks for posting your findings. I'd like to add that to tell it which backup file you would like to read the header of you add it as a device to the restore object via Restore.Devices.Add(). Full example on MSDN, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sqlserver.management.smo.restore.readbackupheader.aspx